# Retry on MassTransit connection

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, connection, masstransit

I have developed a sample code of two microservices (publisher and subscriber) both on separate containers. They use RabbitMq as a separate container for the messaging and MassTransit on top of it. you have all the code here on github:
https://github.com/tabareh/netcore_masstransit_rabbitmq_container.git

As you know it takes a bit of time untill RabbitMq is up and running and that causes my subscriber microservice to fail with RabbitMqConnectionException

The problem is that UseRetry doesn't work on MassTransit. Does anyone know why?

The exact code for retry is here: https://github.com/tabareh/netcore_masstransit_rabbitmq_container/blob/master/subscriber/Configurator.cs

Comment: There is already an issue for this: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1158

Comment: [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) could be an option to implement retry

Comment: Yes, but masstransit should be able to handle that. Will wait until the issue is resolved